# Como executar onChange em checkbox "mascarado"

Tags: jquery

Em um template, é gerado automáticamente a seguinte estrutura e

```js
$(".checkbox-newsletter").change(function() {
  alert('oi');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="icheckbox_minimal checked" aria-checked="true" aria-disabled="false" style="position: relative;">
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-newsletter-1" class="checkbox-newsletter" name="FinlegadoPessoaContato[ativo_newsletter]" value="1" data-id="1" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0;">
<ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 0%; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; opacity: 0; background: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
 
</ins>
</div>
```

Eu precisarei efetuar uma chamada AJAX quando o checkbox tiver seu status alterado. De maneira convencional, o evento não é ativado pois a div `icheckbox_minimal` é quem controla o efeito de `checked`.

Como capturo o evento do checkbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tive de percorrer os elementos e trabalhar com eles da seguinte maneira:

```
$('.iCheck-helper' ).click(function() {

    var input = $(this).prev();
    var parent = $(this).parent();

    if(input.hasClass('checkbox-newsletter')){

        var val = (parent.hasClass('checked')) ? 1 : 0;
        var dataId = input.data('id');

        // A mágica aqui
    }

});
```

@edit

O plugin utilizado era o [icheck](http://icheck.fronteed.com/), ele possue algumas funções de callback pré-definidas para a manipulação dos eventos, dessa forma, foi só chamar:

```
$('input').on('ifChanged', function(event){

    // it's magic

});
```